# Error in getting data from Json in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to access data from `json` in `PHP` but it seems not working.

code:

```
$raw =file_get_contents("http://api.mydomain.com/data.json");
$data = json_decode($raw->list);
echo $data;
```

I'm getting error that list is not an object.

Here is my `json`

```
{ "list" : [ { "data1":" my data"}, {"data2": "my data 2"}]};
```

What did u do wrong? Also how can i access `data1` and others?

Comment: Have you tried running your JSON through a validator? The semi-colon isn't valid which a validator confirms. Try it for yourself by pasting it into JSONLint at http://jsonlint.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$raw->list` bit and you are getting an object back from `json_decode` so use `print_r` and not `echo`

```
$raw = file_get_contents("http://api.mydomain.com/data.json");
$data = json_decode($raw);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: No problem - if this worked then don't forget to give this answer a green tick ;-)

Comment: By the way, if you're less familiar with PHP objects then you can use `$data = json_decode($raw,true);` and you'll get a PHP array instead.